# Using WinRT from Node.js

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-runtime

WinRT makes its full API available to Windows 8 & Windows Server 2012 [JavaScript apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime#JavaScript).

Is it possible for a node.js app running on Windows Server 2012 to get access to this API?

I am asking because not all low level node modules support Windows (e.g. to query metrics) and with WinRT you could access the OS directly.

---

@Roger Rowland - I'm not sure your information is entirely correct.

MSDN says WinRT can be used in non Store Apps - see "[Managed desktop apps and Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx)"

Comment: No, it's not possible. The underlying OS has to be Windows Runtime, which means Surface ARM or Windows 8 x86/64bit. See here - http://getwired.com/2012/05/23/windows-server-2012-and-windows-8-the-fork-in-the-road/

Comment: Interesting, especially since MS indicated that Win32 will become obsolete.

Comment: That is possible. Look at nadavbar's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above - WinRT APIs could be called from regular desktop apps.
So you can write a native node.js addon which consumes WinRT apis to expose them to javascript.

The Javascript Apps in windows 8 uses a different javascript engine (Microsoft's Chakra) & host than node.js, thus you don't get the "built in" support that apps get.

If you are interested in calling WinRT APIs fron node.js - 
We'eve just recently open sourced a new project called NodeRT, which automatically generates node.js native addons which exposes the WinRT APIs into node.js (in the method which is described above): https://github.com/NodeRT/NodeRT

Using this, you should be able to call WinRT APIs from inside node.js.